# How to fix Keras LSTM input / output dimensions?

Tags: python, keras, lstm

My model is:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(input_dim=vocab_size,
                    output_dim=1024, input_length=self.SEQ_LENGTH))

model.add(LSTM(vocab_size))

model.add(Dropout(rate=0.5))
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
print(model.summary())

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'], callbacks=callbacks)
```

The summary is:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
embedding_1 (Embedding)      (None, 100, 1024)         5064704   
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 4946)              118130264 
_________________________________________________________________
dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 4946)              0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 4946)              24467862  
=================================================================
Total params: 147,662,830
Trainable params: 147,662,830
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

But when I run it, I get an error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_1 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (4945,)
```

What do I need to change to get it to match better?

Comment: thats because the y-values of your training data have the wrong shape

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your model is what you want:

```
model.add(LSTM(vocab_size))
```

You don't want a LSTM layer with 4946 neurons.

```
model.add(Dense(vocab_size, activation='softmax'))
```

And I guess you don't want to predict 4946 classes.

```
but got array with shape (4945,)
```

You model expects a dataset, where each row is a list of word indices, where the max index is vocab_size.

What do I need to change to get it to match better?
I think you should take a look at the keras NLP examples. It pretty well explained.

Comment: I think I do want to predict 4945 classes, right? Since that's how many tokens I have?

Comment: Probably, but we don't know, how your data looks like. 4945 classes is a lot.